# TypeError: string indices must be intergers

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

This is the code that is running in `app.py`

```
@app.route("/", subdomain="dev")
def devhome():
    with open("D:/moviewebsite/movielist.json", "r") as f:
        movielist = json.load(f)
    goodmovies = []
    for item in movielist:
        if str(item["link"])[-4:] == ".mp4":
            goodmovies.append(item)
    else:
        return render_template("devHome.html", movielist=goodmovies)
```

This is a snippet of the `movielist.json` file for reference:

```
{
    "12 Years a Slave.mp4": {
        "title": "12 Years a Slave",
        "link": "12 Years a Slave.mp4",
        "count": 1,
        "download": "https://linknotimportant/12 Years a Slave.mp4",
        "torrent": ""
    }
}
```

This is the error message I get:

```
File "d:\moviewebsite\app.py", line 70, in devhome
    if str(item["link"])[-4:] == ".mp4":
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

I am trying to check if the last 4 bits of the string from an array were what I want them to be for the proper file type.

Comment: What do you get if you print `item`? Is it what you expect?

Comment: Aside, use `os.path.splitext` instead.  This function returns a list of filename and extension.

Comment: Did you mean `for item in movielist.values()`? Because I strongly doubt you wanted to work with the dictionary keys.

Comment: Generally, calling a file or variable xxxlist is a bad idea if it doesn't contain a list... (A dictionary isn't a list...)

Comment: _This is a snippet of the `movielist.json` file for reference_ There isn't a **list** anywhere in that json.  Is there supposed to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Answer was opening the dictionary with the item

```
@app.route("/", subdomain="dev")
def devhome():
    with open("D:/moviewebsite/movielist.json", "r") as f:
        movielist = json.load(f)
    goodmovies = []
    for item in movielist:
        if str(movielist[item]["link"])[-4:] == ".mp4":
            goodmovies.append(movielist[item])
    else:
        return render_template("devHome.html", movielist=goodmovies)
```

just because i was in the loop didnt mean i could use the item as an array when the item in the for loop was just a string,

So i had to reopen the dictionary with the item

Answer (score 1):

`json.load` returns the toplevel object in the JSON file - which in your case is a `dict`. Iterating over a `dict` directly gives you strings (the keys of the `dict`).

Replace the `for` loop line with `for key, item in movielist.items():`. Your code would become:

```py
@app.route("/", subdomain="dev")
def devhome():
    with open("D:/moviewebsite/movielist.json", "r") as f:
        movielist = json.load(f)
    goodmovies = []
    for key, item in movielist.items():
        if str(item["link"])[-4:] == ".mp4":
            goodmovies.append(item)
    else:
        return render_template("devHome.html", movielist=goodmovies)
```

Comment: _`json.load` returns a `dict`_ It will return the type of the outermost json object.  Often that is a dict, but it doesn't have to be.

Comment: @JohnGordon right, thanks, corrected in the post.

Answer (score -1):

TL, DR - here's a fix

```py
@app.route("/", subdomain="dev")
def devhome():
    with open("D:/moviewebsite/movielist.json", "r") as f:
        movielist = json.load(f)
    goodmovies = []
    for item in movielist.values():
        if str(item["link"])[-4:] == ".mp4":
            goodmovies.append(item)
    else:
        return render_template("devHome.html", movielist=goodmovies)
```

Explanation:

'movielist' is a dictionary. To iterate through it you need to use .keys(), .values() or .items().